# How to render multiple forms - radiobuttons for answers

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I can't figure out how to create a page with multiple `Question`s and their `Answer`s. The main thing is that I want `User` to take a `Quiz` which contain's multiple `Questions` and `Questions` have multiple `Answers`.

The first thing I want is to render at least one `Question` with it's answers, and if it works, then figure out how to render multiple questions on one page (whole Quiz), but it doesn't render anything except `base.html`.

But when I try to `print question_form` in a view, it returns:

> Exception Type: TypeError at /language-tests/question
>
> Exception Value:'Answer' object is not iterable

Do you have any ideas, what's wrong?

**question.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {{ question_form }}
{% endblock %}
```

**FORM**

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, question, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choice_list = [x for x in question.get_answers_list()]
        self.fields["answers"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list,
                                                   widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

**VIEW** - simple view just for see if the question form can be rendered

```
def question(request):
    question_form = forms.QuestionForm(question=models.Question.objects.get(pk=1))
    return render(request,'question.html',context={'question_form':question_form})
```

**MODELS**

```
class LanguageQuiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    language = models.OneToOneField(sfl_models.Language)
    max_questions = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} test'.format(self.name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.__str__()

class Question(models.Model):
    language_quiz = models.ForeignKey(LanguageQuiz,related_name='questions')
    text = models.TextField()

    def get_answers_list(self):
        return self.answers.all()

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,related_name='answers')
    text = models.TextField()
    correct = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Django form field `choices` argument should be an iterable of 2-tuples, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices

You probably want to say something like

```
choice_list = [(x.id, x.text) for x in question.get_answers_list()]
```

Your exception `'Answer' object is not iterable` is because Django is trying to iterate over this 2-tuple, but finding instead the Answer object.